# How to add a new column to the result table?

Tags: sql, hive

This is the table `mytable`:

```
identifier  thedate            direction
111         2017-06-03 11:20   2
111         2017-06-03 12:22   1
222         2017-06-04 12:15   1
333         2017-06-05 12:21   1
444         2017-06-05 12:39   2
444         2017-06-08 14:23   2
555         2017-06-08 15:33   1
555         2017-06-08 16:12   2
```

I am calculating the average hourly count of unique identifiers in Apache Hive as follows:

```
SELECT HOUR(thedate) as hour, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT identifier, CAST(thedate as date),
       HOUR(thedate)) / COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(thedate as date),
       HOUR(thedate)) as hourly_avg_count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY HOUR(thedate)
```

Now I need to add a new calculated column to the **result table** (not the original one). This column called `newcolumn` should have value `A` for the results of `thedate` from the list `["2017-06-03","2017-06-04"]`. It must have value `B` when `thedate` belongs to `["2017-06-05","2017-06-06"]`. The rest of values of `thedate` that are not included in both lists should have the value `C` assigned.

The resulted table should have the following columns:

```
newcolumn    hour    hourly_avg_count
A            11      0.5
A            12      1
B            ...     ...            
C            ...     ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just add this to the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN DATE(thedate) IN ('2017-06-03', '2017-06-04') THEN 'A'
             WHEN DATE(thedate) IN ('2017-06-05', '2017-06-06') THEN 'B'
             ELSE 'C'
        END) as grp,
       HOUR(thedate) as hour, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT identifier, CAST(thedate as date), HOUR(thedate)
             ) / COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(thedate as date), HOUR(thedate)) as hourly_avg_count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY HOUR(thedate),
         (CASE WHEN DATE(thedate) IN ('2017-06-03', '2017-06-04') THEN 'A'
               WHEN DATE(thedate) IN ('2017-06-05', '2017-06-06') THEN 'B'
               ELSE 'C'
          END);
```

Comment: Can I add the check of the weekend/labour day in the `When` clause? Is there any function that can do this (without passing an exhaustive list of all weekend dates of 2017). If it's a weekend, I want to put `D` and if it's a labour day, then I want to put `E`. Many thanks.

Comment: I get error `cannot resolve 'grp' given input columns: direction`

Comment: Replace the `grp` in `GROUP BY` with the whole `CASE` statement.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks. Why didn't it work with `grp`? Does it depend on the version of `Hive`?

Comment: @Dinosaurius . . . My bad.  I think Hive requires column aliases in `ORDER BY`, but expressions in `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

USE CASE STATEMENT

```
SELECT CASE WHEN thedate BETWEEN '2017-06-03' AND '2017-06-04'
            THEN 'A'
            WHEN thedate BETWEEN '2017-06-05' AND '2017-06-06'
            THEN 'B'
            ELSE 'C'
        END newcolumn
```

...